# global-font-lock-mode not working for python files in emacs

Tags: python, emacs

I cannot seem to turn off syntax highlighting by default in emacs when editing python files.

I am running GNU Emacs 23.1.1 on CentOS release 6.5.  There are only two lines in my .emacs file:

```
(global-font-lock-mode 0)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-g") 'goto-line)
```

My C-g binding works, so I know the file is being read.  When I open or create a .c file, there is no highlighting.  But whenever I open or create a .py file, the syntax highlighting is still there and I have to turn it off with M-x font-lock-mode.  The setting seems to work correctly for other types of code, like .c and .java files.  It's only python where the highlighting still appears.

What's going on here?  Does it have something to do with python-mode?

Answer (score 0):

(global-font-lock-mode 0) should DTRT

Found a bug in components-python-mode, the development-branch of python-mode.el

fixed here

https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-mode/+bug/1410386

also fixed here:

https://github.com/pdee/pdee

Which python-mode do you use?

Comment: I tried that and it gave me an info buffer on customization. Based on what I read there, I tried both (setq global-font-lock-mode nil) and (global-font-lock-mode nil) in my .emacs, but I still have the problem.

Comment: maybe my report helps, I can't reproduce the problem -- everything works fine with (global-font-lock-mode 0) on emacs 24.4

Comment: @KarinLin Please note the difference between font-lock-global-mode and global-font-lock-mode

Comment: @Andreas I typed the command just as you described and got this output:
`font-lock-global-modes: [Hide Value] t
   [State]: STANDARD. (lisp)
   Modes for which Font Lock mode is automagically turned on. [Hide Rest]
   Global Font Lock mode is controlled by the command `global-font-lock-mode'.`
This suggests to me that the actual command is in fact "global-font-lock-mode" and not "font-lock-global-mode"`

I would like to know what to put in the .emacs file.

Comment: Thanks @Andreas.  I am using Emacs 23.1.1 and supposedly python.el is included, but I can't find the actual file.  However, the Emacs info help (C-h a) shows me this:

`Major mode for editing Python files.
Turns on Font Lock mode unconditionally since it is currently required
for correct parsing of the source.`

Comment: Currently shipped python.el doesn't work with Emacs23. You could give python-mode.el a try: http://launchpad.net/python-mode